# Maven transitive dependency not updating, shows older version

Tags: maven

I have modules as below:

```
root
  daemon
  common
  tests
```

Now `daemon` and `test` both have `<dependency>common</dependency>`.
I have written them just in brief to understand.

`common` has `jaxrs-api` version `2.1.1`, earlier it was `2.0`.

Built the whole project, cleaned it, but still `daemon` and `tests` show older version. `common` version is consistent across all modules. Dependency Analyzer plugin in IntelliJ still shows `common` having 2.0 and code has compilation issues due to mismatch.

[image]

Each module's version is coming from root as follows:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Apart from screenshot above, below are the only jax-rs entries in `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ common ---
[INFO] com.zzz:common:jar:1.0.10-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:6.9.6:test



[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ daemon ---
[INFO] com.zzz:daemon:jar:1.0.10-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.zzz:common:jar:1.0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.paypal.usf:vo:jar:1.6.5:compile
```

See the `daemon` dependency log for issue, its brining older version of `common` with `2.0`. I don't see any conflicts or the jar coming from other dependencies. I have also tried manually deleted the `target` directories and delete the directories inside `.m2` but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Run maven dependency:tree and check where the dependency of interest is present.

Maven always take teansitive dependency that is available at less distance from the root node.

Refer - https://dzone.com/articles/solving-dependency-conflicts-in-maven

Comment: Same thing as dependency analyzer. Same `common` version but with 2.0 jar version.

Comment: Ok, if '2.0' is before '2.1.1' then **2.0** willie taken

Comment: no, 2.0 is not there. i have changed it. there were other deps bringing that jar but i have excluded them. so if you see my screenshot, its only coming from common, same snapshot, but older version. earlier it was 2.0, i changed the version to 2.1.

Comment: Updated answer with blog post url for help, pls check.